# Any downsides to exclusively using SVG image files?

Tags: html, css, image, svg, responsive-design

I'm building a photography portfolio website, which will have a fluid, responsive design.  To have the images look good at all sizes, and to not have to deal with retina resolution issues, I'm thinking of just using SVG files for all images.

Using SVGs sounds like a perfect solution to these issues, but for some reason I haven't seen any websites exclusively use them, which makes me wonder if there are any downsides to them (aside from lack of support in IE8, which I don't care about).

Comment: It seems like your question should be in http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What type of images do you want to have in SVG format? While it sounds good for icons/sprites/cartoons (that tend to be more vector-ish), I don't think SVG is an appropriate format for photos

Comment: For all images on the site, including photos.  Why isn't SVG an appropriate format for photos?

Comment: There is no benefits in SVG for bitmap images (photos). You'll just get your file size (much) bigger

Answer (score 1):

If you use them too much, or in animated form the end user might have some performance issues, especially on smart phones. Icon fonts are much CPU-friendly, but they are much simple and monochromatic.

Other than the lack of support for older-browsers, there's no downside to them. We love SVGs.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, I would go with SVG icons/sprites/cartoons, and stick to bitmap/raster formats for photos. Photographs are bitmaps by nature, and when trying to convert them to vectors you may find some issues:

- Not everything can be converted into a vector... or it could, but at a high price (**bigger file size**, complex files that require **more processing**). Then we could start a whole debate about file size vs image quality.
- You are limited by the camera/lens technology: using photos in SVG may give crispier/sharper edges on scale, but the **details inside won't appear because they are not there** (e.g.: you may have a picture of a hand in SVG, but it doesn't matter how much you zoom in, you may prevent pixelation but you won't see the cells either).
- **Older browsers will not support** the format (although you already mentioned that this is not a problem in your case).

Then there are other issues specific to a photography portfolio/store website:

- If you are planning on selling the pictures, by using SVG **you'd be giving the product away** for free: right-click, "Save image as..." and the user will have the full size image without paying.
- You could add a message/watermark to prevent that (or to sign/give credit to yourself), but **watermarks would be "easy" to remove**. And sadly we all know [how the Internet works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xo2gn.jpg).